# Did Emma have an abortion?

Tags: plot-explanation, terms-of-endearment

In [*Terms of Endearment*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086425/), there is a scene depicting a visibly pregnant Emma Horton looking like she is starting the second trimester (just a guess) of her pregnancy while she is on the phone with her mother, Aurora:

> **Emma**:  Don't yell, but I really think that I might be pregnant again.
>
> **Aurora**:  Oh, no!  And, you're going to have it, I suppose?
>
> **Emma**:  Yes, of course!  What's happening to you, anyways?
>
> **Aurora**:  Don't act like that's so terrible.  Bright young women are
>   having simple abortions.
>
> **Emma**:  Simple?

After this scene, Emma is in the supermarket with her 2 boys and she is visibly not pregnant anymore and she does not have a baby with her.

I am aware that she does have a baby girl later.  **Is her baby girl the child that she was carrying during the call with her mother?**

I realize that I might have missed a scene since I watched this on television.  **Did her mother convince her to abort that child and she got pregnant later with her daughter?**

Comment: *"Is her baby girl the child that she was carrying during the call with her mother?"* - Yes

Comment: @Paulie_D Another reason that I was questioning this was the look that Emma's older son gave her when her husband takes her daughter and says "she sure knows who her daddy is" This is after her affair with the bank manager.  I didn't know if they were insinuating that he was the father of her daughter, but I don't recall him coming into the movie until after her daughter was born.